# How to manage Views in a Listview correctly

Tags: android, listview, view

I am wondering how to manage the views inside a ListView.

I have a custom Adapter that is set on the ListView, this Adapter overrides the getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater_.inflate(R.layout.news_newsentry, null);
        }

        final NewsItem newsItem = getItem(position);

        if (newsItem != null) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        return v;

    }
```

But the thing is that when the user clicks on an item, I slightly change the view to make it bigger. It works well, but when the item view is recycled, it keeps the "big" height to display another item.

To prevent that, I changed the code to create a new View each time

Change:

```
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater_.inflate(R.layout.news_newsentry, null);
    }
```

By

```
    View v = mInflater_.inflate(R.layout.news_newsentry, null);
```

The problem now is that when the item disappears from the list and reappears (the list is scrolled), the view is completely new and the height is set to "small".

My question then: **how to manage the items views to keeps their properties, without messing with the other views and the view recycling?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the result you want by using the ListView built in support for more than one view type in a list.

In your adapter you would implement additional methods similar to

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int type = 0;
        if (position == mySelectedPosition) {
            type = 1;
        }
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

Then your getView method will be handed a view of the correct type for the position of the item.  Ie, the selected item will always be given a "big" view to re-use.

Creating a new View every time is not recommended for performance and memory reasons.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be a solution, but: what if there can be any sort of configuration for each list item. Do I have to keep track of all of them by myself?